# problema con encabezado y footer con tablas en html

Tags: php, html, css, pdf

Tengo un problema con mi codigo html el cual tengo una tabla que actua como encabezado pero el "footer" que tengo se pega al encabezado de esta forma
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero deberia quedar asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

adjunto el codigo html

```html
<p class="footer";><strong>Departamento de las TIC &ldquo;Tecnologias de la Informacion y la Comunicaci&oacute;n&rdquo;</strong></p>
<p class="footer";>Swisslub S.A.S - Bogot&aacute;, Colombia</p>
<p class="footer";>Avenida el Dorado No. 100 &ndash; 45 of.302</p>
<p class="footer";>Tel&egrave;fono:+57 (1) 742 7233 ext 579 - 575</p>
<p class="footer";>pablo.cardenas@swisslub.com</p>
<p class="footer";>www.swisslub.com</p>
<br><br><br><br>


<table style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="1"; width="530">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td width="100"  rowspan="4">
      <img src="img/44.png" alt="" class="logo">
     </td>
     <td>
      <p align="center"><font size=1> PROCESO DE GESTIÓN DE RECURSOS</p>
     </td>
     <td width="100">
      <p align="center"><font size=1> CÓDIGO</p>
     </td>
     <td  colspan="3" >
      <p align="center"><font size=1>  FSW-100</p>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td  >
      <p align="center">
      <font size=1> <strong>DEPARTAMENTO DE LAS TIC</strong>
      <strong></strong>
      </p>
     </td>
     <td  rowspan="2">
      <p align="center">
      <font size=1> VERSIÓN 1
      </p>
     </td>
     <td  colspan="3" rowspan="2">
      <p align="center">
      <font size=1>  01-12-17
      </p>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <p align="center">
       <font size=1>   Tecnologías de la información y las comunicaciones
      </p>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <p  align="center" >
      <font size=2>   <strong>Acta de Entrega</strong></font>
      </p>
     </td>
     <td>
      <p align="center">
      <font size=1>    PAGINA
      </p>
     </td>
     <td  width="20">
      <p align="center">
      <font size=1>    1
      </p>
     </td>
     <td   width="20">
      <p align="center">
      <font size=1>    DE
      </p>
     </td>
     <td  width="20">
      <p align="center">
      <font size=1>  2
      </p>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>

   '
```

PD: estoy trabajando en php es un informe que tengo que crear estoy con dompdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que puedas insertar un footer estatico, puedes usar estos estilos

```css
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -40px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

De este modo el `div#footer` estará presente en todas las páginas:

```
<div id="footer">
   <p><strong>Departamento de las TIC &ldquo;Tecnologias de la Informacion y la Comunicaci&oacute;n&rdquo;</strong></p>
   <p>Swisslub S.A.S - Bogot&aacute;, Colombia</p>
   <p>Avenida el Dorado No. 100 &ndash; 45 of.302</p>
   <p>Tel&egrave;fono:+57 (1) 742 7233 ext 579 - 575</p>
   <p>pablo.cardenas@swisslub.com</p>
   <p>www.swisslub.com</p>
</div>
```

Adapta la medida de `bottom` a la posición que desees.

Comment: lo remplazo por el .footer?

Comment: No es necesario que a todos las etiquetas `p` le añadas la clase `.footer`, es mejor que lo encapsules en un `div` que tenga el nuevo id `#footer`.

Comment: ya lo hice pero no me cogia el #footer

Answer (score 0):

recuerda que le pongas una clase footer no significa que ira al final deberás hacer esto con css pero tambien te aconsejo agrupar todas las cosas en una sola div con clase footer.

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
 
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
<p ><strong>Departamento de las TIC &ldquo;Tecnologias de la Informacion y la Comunicaci&oacute;n&rdquo;</strong></p>
<p >Swisslub S.A.S - Bogot&aacute;, Colombia</p>
<p >Avenida el Dorado No. 100 &ndash; 45 of.302</p>
<p >Tel&egrave;fono:+57 (1) 742 7233 ext 579 - 575</p>
<p >pablo.cardenas@swisslub.com</p>
<p >www.swisslub.com</p>
</div>
```

Comment: no lo que pasa es que arriba tengo el css que se llama footer